# How to create many individual uglify tasks in grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

when I try to create many uglify tasks I get errors. I have to comment and uncomment one task in order to get one task working correctly. Hope someone can help me. I need two sperate minified .js files created using this plugin but I can't figure it out. if it's possible to create both tasks in one task command that would create two sperate minified .js files like below that would be also great. Looking forward to ideas, please.

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify:{
        t1:{
            files:{
                'build/scripts1.js' : ['abc.js', 'xc.js']

            }
        }
    },

    uglify:{
        t2:{
            files:{
                'build/scripts2.js' : ['123.js', 63a5.js]

            }
        }
    }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add both [Targets](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) `t1` and `t2` to one single `uglify` [Task](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) as follows:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    uglify:{
      t1:{
        files:{
          'build/scripts1.js' : [ 'abc.js', 'xc.js' ]
        }
      },
      t2:{
        files:{
            'build/scripts2.js' : [ '123.js', '63a5.js' ]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ["uglify"]);
  grunt.registerTask('foo', ["uglify:t1"]);
  grunt.registerTask('quux', ["uglify:t2"]);
};
```

**Running grunt**

The `Gruntfile.js` above has three [registerTask](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registertask)'s, namely; `default`, `foo`, and `quux`.

- Running `$ grunt` will run both Targets `t1` and `t2`
- Running `$ grunt foo` will run Target `t1` only.
- Running `$ grunt quux` will run Target `t2` only.

Both `foo` and `quux` use the colon notation (I.e. `"uglify:t1"` and `"uglify:t2"`) to reference only one of the Targets.

The `default` task references only `uglify` which will result in all targets (however many) in the `uglify` target being run.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, and very detailed explanation I really appreciate it.